# Quasar : Placing a counter inside the select menu's placeholder

Tags: quasar-framework

When I use the built-in counter it is placed right under the select menu placeholder. Is there a way to have it placed inseide the placeholder, next to the "clearable" icon?

codepen example : https://codepen.io/jonathank2018/pen/PoJgNJp

```
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-select
      filled
      hide-bottom-space
      options-dense
      hide-dropdown-icon
      v-model="model"
      use-input
      clearable
      multiple
      input-debounce="500"
      :options="filterOptions"
      @filter="filterFn"
      style="width: 200px"
      counter
      hint="Selected items"        
      label="Actors"
      dense
      hide-selected
    ></q-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quasar has an `#append` slot that might be what you're looking for.

```html
<q-select
  filled
  hide-bottom-space
  options-dense
  hide-dropdown-icon
  v-model="model"
  use-input
  clearable
  multiple
  input-debounce="500"
  :options="filterOptions"
  @filter="filterFn"
  style="width: 200px"
  counter
  hint="Selected items"        
  label="Actors"
  dense
  hide-selected
>
  <template #append>
    {{ model.length }}
  </template>
</q-select>
```

Quasar also has a default slot so this might be what you want (outer code removed for verbosity):

```html
<q-select
  v-model="model"
  multiple
>
  {{ model.length }}
</q-select>
```

See the bottom examples in the docs here: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#decorators

You'll also want to make your model an array by default so that `.length` isn't used on null:

```js
// model: ref(null) // change from null
model: ref(null) // to empty array
```

This is also [covered in Quasar's QSelect video on quasarcomponent.com](https://quasarcomponents.com/)